# Uncaught ReferenceError:- variable is not defined(recursive calling)

Tags: javascript

I'm having the problem

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: fg_my_content is not defined
    at flipGallery (flipgallery.min.js:53)
    at asdfg (Albumfinal.php:420)
    at onload (Albumfinal.php:21)
```

Here's my code

```
<body onload="loadContent()">
.
.
.
.
    <!-- DOM area must be loaded before executing scripts-->
    <!-- /DOM area must be loaded before executing scripts-->
    <script>
        function loadContent(){
            var fg_my_content1 = <?= json_encode($fg_my_content)?>;
            var fg_my_content2 = <?= json_encode($fg_my_content2)?>;
            var fg_my_content=fg_my_content1;
            flipGallery();
            fg_my_content=fg_my_content2;
            flipGallery2();
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="flipgallery/flipgallery.min.js"></script><!-- has a function that uses variable fg_my_content -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="flipgallery2/flipgallery.min.js"></script><!-- has a function that uses variable fg_my_content -->
</body>
```

Where the value of `json_encode($fg_my_content)` comes from php

```
{
"user":{
        "name": "something",
        "age": 20,
        "phonenumber": "321456987"
    }
}
```

and the function that uses variable `fg_my_content` looks something like

```
//flipgallery/flipgallery.min.js
function flipGallery(){
    .
    .
    .
    doSomethingWith(fg_my_content);
    .
    .
    .
}
//flipgallery2/flipgallery.min.js
function flipGallery2(){
    .
    .
    .
    doSomethingWith(fg_my_content);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

What my code should do is loading the html DOM then call the function `loadContent()` which should declare the variable `fg_my_content` then call the function `flipGallery()`. but for some reason the variable `fg_my_content` is not defined in the function `flipGallery()`. Why is that?

Why is the variable `fg_my_content` not defined inside `flipGallery()` even when I'm declaring it before calling the function?

Comment: `fg_my_content` is only defined in `loadContent` - you need to pass it to the two `flipGallery` functions (as a parameter) or make it a global variable (which is usually the less preferred choice)

Comment: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/scope%20%26%20closures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either define fg_my_content as global like following:

```
<script>
        var fg_my_content;
        function loadContent(){
            var fg_my_content1 = <?= json_encode($fg_my_content)?>;
            var fg_my_content2 = <?= json_encode($fg_my_content2)?>;
            fg_my_content=fg_my_content1;
            flipGallery();
            fg_my_content=fg_my_content2;
            flipGallery2();
        }
</script>
```

or
   pass the value fg_my_content to the function